# GCC 4.2 warning for object that no longer exsists

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, properties

I had an NSString named responseReference that I put in a @property like so...

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *responseReference;
```

and I got the warning:

```
No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed
Assign attribute (default) not appropriate for non-gc object property 'responseReference'
```

So to simply fix it I changed the code to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *responseReference;
```

but I still got the warnings. I tried many things and ended up trying to remove the warnings by just removing the object from existence. But even when responseReference was no longer a part of ANY of my code it still gave me the exact same warning for responseReference. So I restarted X-Code. No beans.

Can anyone explain why it's giving me these warnings even though the object it's talking about doesn't exist? Also, do these warnings mean that my compiled code is affected?

Comment: Is the property really named `responseRefernce` while the error says `responseReference`?

Comment: No, that was a typo in here. But even when there is NO responseReference object, it STILL has the warning.

Comment: Have you tried a 'Clean All' and re-build?

Comment: Thanks Kyle, it worked. I forgot I have that option because I have xCode 4 and the layout is completely different. :P